# getting Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'deadline' in laravel migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, database-migration

I'm migrating table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExamsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->enum('type',['iq','math','geo','gen']);
            $table->string('notes');
            $table->boolean('vip');
            $table->string('rate');
            $table->integer('hardness');
            $table->string('quode');
            $table->timestamp('bornline');
            $table->timestamp('deadline', $precision = '0000-00-00');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exams');
    }
}
```

the cmd returning this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
> default value for 'deadline' (SQL: create table `exams` (`id` bigint
> unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not
> null, `type` enum('iq', 'math', 'geo', 'gen') not null, `notes`
> varchar(191) not null, `vip` tinyint(1) not null, `rate` varchar(191)
> not null, `hardness` int not null, `quode` varchar(191) not null,
> `bornline` timestamp not null, `deadline` timestamp not null,
> `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default
> character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
>
> at
> C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\deneme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:705
> 701▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 702▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 703▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 704▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 705▕             throw new QueryException(
> 706▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 707▕             );
> 708▕         }
> 709▕     }
>
> C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\deneme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:494
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'deadline'")
>
> C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\deneme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:494
> PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: I'm creating it form laravel I can't modify the SQL syntax

Comment: It would be `$table->timestamp('deadline', $precision = 0);`

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'deadline'

Comment: '0000-00-00'  is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fractional seconds precision (fsp) doesn't have a format like `0000-00-00`. The fsp value, if given, **must be in the range `0` to `6`**.

With `0000-00-00` format, I believe that you want to create a default value for `deadline` column. You can use `default()` method :

```
$table->timestamp('deadline')->default('0000-00-00');
```

Or `nullable()` method, to allow `NULL` values to be entered into a column :

```
$table->timestamp('deadline')->nullable();
```